# Reset Rootscope values in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

`$route.reload()` methods does not work.

Is there any other method available to reset the rootscope values?

Comment: you need to set `$rootScope` value to `null` explicitly

Comment: Why do you need to reset rootScope? If you need to do that then it seems you are using it for things it shouldn't be used for

Comment: while logout i need to clear all the rootscope values.If i am login again with different user,same data is exists in rootscope. For this reason, i need to clear the rootscope while logout.